# How do I get whatever default style <h2> has, without having my text on a single line?

Tags: html, css

I realize that in the modern day, most people use CSS to perform styling, and will have CSS define what H2 looks like.

However, please imagine that I'm trying to make my text looks like it is the default appearance of <h2>, but have it on a line with other text.

Is it possible to do this in HTML4?

Alternatively, is it possible to emulate it using CSS?
Assume I am NOT setting a style on <h2> directly.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Did you try `display: inline` or `display: inline-block`?

Comment: Going to try that now, thanks.

Comment: @bfavaretto I would make an answer of that, it's as good as it will get :)

Comment: @bfavaretto, that does exactly what I needed. Sorry I'm not very experienced in web design.

Comment: Okay, added an answer explaining it a bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, all HTML headings (`<h1>` to `<h5>`) are displayed as `block`. This means a heading will be in a separate line if there is other elements surrounding it.

You can change that with CSS by applying `display: inline` to your heading. If you need it to keep some block behavior (like having a certain width, for example), you can use `display: inline-block` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Give a try to that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<style>
.h2{
   font-size: x-large;
   font-weight: bold;
   display: inline;
}
</style>

<h1>This is heading 1</h1>
<h2>This is heading 2</h2>
<p class="h2">This is heading 2</p>
<h3>This is heading 3</h3>
<h4>This is heading 4</h4>
<h5>This is heading 5</h5>
<h6>This is heading 6</h6>

</body>
</html>
```

And you should disable your current styles applying to the current h2.
For example: color: black !important; (if it's defined)

Comment: Also, to make it in line with the other text, use `<span class="h2">This is heading 2</span>`.

Answer (score 2):

You can make the h2 display inline with the following CSS:

```
​h2 { display: inline; }​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8AYRj/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a `<span>` on the text in question and add an h2 class to the span.

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonstodle/kZxLf/)

```
.header2{
    font-size: 120%;
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it in HTML4 (which is what the question was primarily about) is to use two-cell table:

```
<table><tr valign=baseline><td><h2>Your heading</h2> <td>Other text</table>
```

Not many people would recommend this these days.

Note: The only way to ensure that the default rendering of `h2` (which is browser-dependent, though tends to follow similar lines) is to refrain from using any CSS rule that could apply to an `h2` element. I don’t see any particular reason to want to achieve that, though, perhaps on a page that discusses HTML rendering in browsers, or something similar.